# Remove meta information in picture using "convert" without changing the colors of the picture

Tags: image, imagemagick

I have a problem using the tool `convert` (imagemagick) to remove metainformation of pictures to make them smaller for faster delivery in websites.

When I use the convert command with following parameters:

> convert -format png -strip pic1.png pic2.png

then the converted picture is much more darker than the original one.

I also tried to require the colorspace of the original picture with:

> convert -format png -colorspace sRGB -strip pic1.png pic2.png

but it's the same problem.

Has anyone an idea how to solve it?

These are the example pictures:

(Original) Pic1: [image: pic1]

(Converted) Pic 2: [image: pic2]

Comment: The following command works fine with ImageMagick 6.9.0-10 Q16 x86_64 2015-03-10.... `convert in.png -strip out.png`

Comment: Thank you, the problem is my version, with another pc with ImageMagick 6.4 it works also, so my version (6.7.7) is buggy in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the installed version 6.7.7 of ImageMagick (Standard-Version of Linux Mint 17)

In version 6.4 and (said in comment) in version 6.9 it works.

So the 6.7.7 version is buggy in that case.